# Hibernate - filter child collection by child collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities:

1. Page Group - contains pages.
2. Page - below to Page Group, has access roles.
3. Role.

I need to query all Page Groups which are allowed to one (or several) selected roles. Queried Page Group can contain not all it's pages. All Pages queried for Page Group must have selected roles.

How can I realise this? Think I must use @Filter but don't know how.

Database scheme is bellow:
[image]

Page Group listing:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PAGE_GROUP")
public class PageGroup {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "pg_id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "SOME_FIELD")
    private String field;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
    private Set<Page> pages;
}
```

Page listing:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "page")
public class Page {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "p_id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "some_field")
    private String field;
    @JoinColumn(name = "pg_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private PageGroup group;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

Role listing

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "r_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "some_field")
    private Date field;
    //important: no Page reference
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have used to _try_ to implement the query?

Answer (score 0):

In JPQL you could use the following query:

```
SELECT pg FROM PageGroup pg LEFT JOIN pg.pages p LEFT JOIN p.roles r
WHERE r.id IN (....<list of Ids you want>....)
```

That will return a list of `PageGroup` objects that have pages associated to the roles identified by the given list of role ids.

Comment: 1. Need add "distinct" keyword. Without it returns duplicates of PageGroup.  
2. Not working. Returned PageGroups contain Pages which are anavaliable for selected roles.

Comment: The `PageGroups` returned should have _at least one_ page with the specified roles. Make sure you are not lazy-loading _all_ the pages just by looking at them. In fact, if your associations are fetch lazy (which they should be by default), then the query should only return `PageGroup` objects with nothing attached. Remember, even the debugger will trigger lazy-loading if you try to examine the 'contents' of an Entity. No idea why you needed distinct, unless you were using a native query.

Comment: OK, tried a similar query with our data and, yes, you do need the DISTINCT keyword. But the `PageGroup` objects returned should have **no** pages attached to them by default. Unfortunately, if you want the `PageGroup` objects to have only the matching `Page` objects attached, then there is no standard JPA way to do this. However, Hibernate can do this using [the @filter annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-filters).